# The OwinStartup attribute discovered in assembly 'XXX' referencing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, owin

I don't have complex scenario as other SO questions. It is straingth one.

I created a new project in `ASP.Net MVC` and installed `Owin` and `SignalR`. Wrote the following code

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebChat.Models.ChatHub))]
namespace WebChat.Models{

    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessage(string username, string msg)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(username, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

and following code in js.

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                chat.server.send($('#lblusername').val(), $('#txtMsg').val());
                $('#txtMsg').val('').focus();
            });
        });
```

and I am getting this error

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - The OwinStartup attribute discovered in assembly 'WebChat' referencing startup type 'WebChat.Startup' conflicts with the
>   attribute in assembly 'WebChat' referencing startup type
>   'WebChat.Models.ChatHub' because they have the same FriendlyName ''.
>   Remove or rename one of the attributes, or reference the desired type
>   directly. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting
>   owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the
>   appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or
>   configuration method name in your web.config.

I know this has been asked at many places but none solved my issue.

Comment: did anyone get the solution for this issue. Looks like I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files in the debug and release folder, then rebuild your application.
As simple as that.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work, for me anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Faced somewhat similar problem, Steps that lead to problem then solution

1. Mistake committed

a. copied API project bin to UI project while publishing.
b. (didn't noticed this, kept on working on API project)

2. API project was working fine and UI was throwing internal server error

a. Tried publishing both projects again multiple times but problem persisted.

Solution
"manually delete the bin and other folders(as required) and then copy new ones." as it might be happening that bin and other folders are being merged with old corrupted bin which contains orphaned files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).